# Installing pymake?

Tags: python, building

There dont seem to be any instructions on how to build this sucker.  Downloaded from http://benjamin.smedbergs.us/pymake/

The usual files are not in the top directory - make.py and mkparse.py.  neither of them seem to do much..  seems like it needs a makefile, but there isn't one in any part of the distro..

```
> python make.py build
make.py[0]: Entering directory '/Users/ron/lib/pymake-default'
No makefile found
```

any hints?

Comment: Does this help at all: http://www.python.org/ftp/python/contrib-09-Dec-1999/System/pymake.README

Comment: @mwan: That appears to be a different pymake.

Answer (score 3):

pymake *is* a make utility, and running `make.py` looks for a `Makefile` (that you've created, for your own project). There's no build step specifically required for pymake itself.

Comment: thanks - that's helpful.  there's no Makefile in the project i'm trying to use pymake on, but that's their problem :| The projects README tells me to invoke pymake from the command line like this: "pymake" which I can't do...?

Comment: Well, the "pymake" you're asking about is intended to do exactly the same thing as "make" except it's written in Python. Must you use pymake, and if so, have you got the correct pymake? Also, what if you simply use "make" instead?

Comment: as you can see there is no Makefile (or makefile or ... etc) to be had.  I'm nosing around for some other clues, but nobody has touched the code for a few years so i'm getting discouraged... :(